# x86 MASM Beginner Question about DUP storage

Tags: x86, masm

I know that you can create storage for multiple items using the DUP operator. I want to first create an uninitialized array by doing this

```
 array WORD 5 DUP(?)
```

in the .data segment. But now how do I store the values in the array. Would something like this work?

```
mov [array],    10   ;first member
mov [array+2],  20  ;second member
mov [array+4],  30  ;third member
mov [array+6],  40  ;fourth member
mov [array+8],  50  ;fifth member
```

I also would like to know i would be able to see the values inside the array like if i wanted to see the value 10 which would the be the first element in the array

Comment: Use a debugger to look at the memory in the array.  And yes, those instructions would store to the array.  The `word` operand-size is implied in MASM because of the way you declared `array`.  Otherwise you'd need `mov word ptr [array], 10` so the assembler knows you want a 16-bit store, instead of 8 or 32.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.shsu.edu/~csc_tjm/fall2002/cs272/intro_to_asm.html

MOV destination,source

- reg, reg
- mem, reg
- reg, mem
- mem, immed
- reg, immed

Addresses with Displacements -

```
b    db  4Fh, 20h, 3Ch 
w    dw  2048, -100, 0

mov b+1, ah 
mov ah, b+5
```

Simply specify the name of your label with an offset.